# get the style property of document.activeElement.id

Tags: javascript

I would like to know the style property of the focused element. my code doesn't work:

```
alert(document.activeElement.id.style.border);
```

but it shows the id using this code:

```
alert(document.activeElement.id);
```

Any help?
I prefer not to use jquery . I'm doing a project on IE 7 . and I know a lot of you thinks IE 7 is not a browser .

Comment: An `id` does not have a `style`. An element does.

Comment: Drop the ID from your style selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` is a property of the relevant `node`, the `style` is also a property of the node, so replace `id` with `style.border` (the `id` has no properties of its own, except those properties inherent to strings, as it is, merely, a *string*) to give:

```
document.activeElement.style.border;
```

As it was written, you were trying to access the `style` property of the string, which is non-existent and therefore undefined.

To access the individual properties of the `border`:

```
document.activeElement.style.borderStyle;
document.activeElement.style.borderWidth;
```

And so on, to access the individual properties of individual borders (`border-left`, `border-right` etc):

```
document.activeElement.style.borderLeftWidth;
document.activeElement.style.borderLeftStyle;
```

And, again, so on...

To respond to the comment left by the OP (in another answer):

> but why this code: `alert(document.activeElement.style.borderColor);` shows a blank alert?

The problem may be that the styles are defined in a stylesheet, whereas the `style` property only accesses those styles in the `style` *attribute* of an element. In contemporary browsers, you need to look at the `window.getComputedStyle()` to see the computed rendered output of the styling, for example:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.activeElement, null).border;
```

Internet Explorer has the alternative (in some versions) of the `currentStyle` object, but without IE, or Windows, I'm unable to offer insight. There is a link in the references, below, that will take you to Microsoft's documentation.

References:

- [`currentStyle` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style).
- [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle).

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at `element.style`, not `element.id.style`. The element's ID does not have a style.

```
alert(document.activeElement.style.border);
```

Comment: but why this code: alert(document.activeElement.style.borderColor); shows a blank alert ?

Comment: The active element probably doesn't have a borderColor style property. Have a look at document.activeElement.style in your browser's JS console.